# Need help implementing php in js

Tags: javascript, php

Hello stackoverflow community, i have a problem with a project i'm working on.
I tryied a few methods to get this working but the best i think it will be to echo with php. So, here is how i did (on lines 20 and 21):

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     "use strict";
     var changeTrack = function changeTrack(event) {
         var current = myPlaylist.current,
          playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;       
         $.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
             if (index == current) {
                 $("#nowPlaying .artist-name").html(obj.artist);
                 $("#nowPlaying .track-name").html(obj.title);
             }
         });
     };
     
  var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
   jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
   cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
  }, [
   {
    artist:"<?php echo $artist; ?>",
    title:"<?php echo $track; ?>",
    mp3:"http://<?php echo $ipport; ?>/api/v1/bot/i/<?php echo $inst; ?>/stream/<?php echo $sinusbot->getWebStreamToken($inst); ?>"
   }
  ],{
   playlistOptions: {
       enableRemoveControls: false,
       autoPlay: true
   },
   swfPath: "assets/jplayer/jplayer",
   supplied: "ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
   wmode: "window",
   useStateClassSkin: true,
   autoBlur: false,
   smoothPlayBar: false, //removes bar jittery
            ready: changeTrack,
      play: changeTrack
  });
 });//end .ready
 </script>
```

Also i tryied to include the php file with `require 'getSong.php';` and with `include("getSong.php");` but its just crashing the site. Here is the php file:

```css
<?php
error_reporting('E_ERROR');
include("sinusbot.class.php");
include("config.php");
$sinusbot = new SinusBot($ipport);
$sinusbot->login($user, $passwd);
$status = $sinusbot->getStatus($inst);
$track = (($status["currentTrack"]["type"] == "url") ? $status["currentTrack"]["tempTitle"] : $status["currentTrack"]["title"]);
$artist = $status["currentTrack"]["tempArtist"];
$name = $track;
$track = preg_replace('^ ^', '+', $track);

if(!empty($artist)) {
echo $name." from ".$artist;
} else {
echo $name;
}
```

Forgot to tell you guys what is this about... 
I want from this js to automatically get the track name/artist.

I will put down here the old method that was used for getSong.php, the js:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadSong() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("getSong").innerHTML = "" + xhttp.responseText;
   }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getSong.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
 } 

 function loadImg() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("getImg").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
   }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getImg.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
 
 function loadSearch() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
   }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "search.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
 
setInterval(function() {
 loadImg();
 loadSong();
 loadSearch();
}, 3500); 
</script>
```

And it was working by just puting the div ids somewhere in the page...

```html
    <div id="getImg">Loading...</div>
 <div id="search">Loading...</div>
 <div id="getSong">Please Wait...</div>
```

Comment: Is there an error you get? What does your console say?

Comment: I'm using the site on local with XAMPP and i checked php_error_log and nothing shows up and in the web browser console(Mozilla) i this error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More]  radio:180:5
 loadImg/xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: It sounds like there isn't an element with the id of getSong.

Comment: @anyber When i use the div ids in the page the errors are gone, but this is still not helping me with my problem. :)

Comment: You can't have PHP codes inside the your JS codes because PHP is executed server-side while JS is client-side.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio, then why 'mp3:"http://<?php echo $ipport; ?>/api/v1/bot/i/<?php echo $inst; ?>/stream/<?php echo $sinusbot->getWebStreamToken($inst); ?>"' is working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (if you use PHP without a framework):

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='app_script.php'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(func());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app_script.php**

```
$str = 'test';
include("app.js");
```

**app.js**

```
var func = function() {
    return "<?php echo $str; ?>";
};
```

Comment: I'm not quiet sure that i understand, i configurated the files from your example for my website but what should i put in my js ? I tryied like this:     `artist:"test",
title:"",` but is not working.

Comment: @1Example you can put PHP code into JS. For example: `artist:"<?php echo $artist; ?>", title:"<?php echo $track; ?>"`. Research attentively my example, it works. All that you need is to configure your PHP and JS files properly, because I dont know how you have configurated your files.

Comment: I don't understand a thing, my way is working on 'mp3:"http://<?php echo $ipport; ?>/api/v1/bot/i/<?php echo $inst; ?>/stream/<?php echo $sinusbot->getWebStreamToken($inst); ?>"' but not on 'artist:"",
    title:"",'